# Upgrading from Neo4j 2.1.7 to 2.2.0

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I was using Neo4j 2.1.7 without any problems. Beside running Cypher queries in the web client provided by Neo4j, I also played with the Java API in a Maven project where I created some nodes and relationships. All worked fine.
My problems began when I decided to upgrade to version 2.2.0. First, I unistalled the older version, and installed the newer one which is 2.2.0. I started the server:
[image: Starting the server]

I tried to run a simple query and got 'Unknown Error':
[image: Performing a simple query]

At first I thought that the database located at C:\Users\AugustinUser\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb was from the previous version, so I deleted it and created a new one that would comply with version 2.2.0. But I get the same error. Need some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem after upgrading too. Try clear cache of your browser. Push `CTRL` + `F5`.

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade your existing data, make a backup and then.
Enable `allow_store_upgrade=true` in the neo4j.properties file (Under `Options`)

Shift+Reload helps with the browser.

Comment: Is Spring Data Neo4j 3.3.0.RELEASE compatible with Neo4j 2.2.0?

Comment: @geceo Looks like SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE & 4.0.0.M1 reference neo4j v2.1.7. Check out the neo4j.version property in the project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/3.3.0.RELEASE/pom.xml && https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/4.0.0.M1/pom.xml